# Rejected flag for dangerous, potentially trolling post

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340193/is-it-possible-to-customize-properties-window-toolbar-in-visual-studio-altf4) (now removed by user) asked people to press to hotkey "alt-f4" to open the properties window in visual studio. This would force close the application potentially losing work for anyone who attempted to try and answer the question. I flagged it as rude/offensive since to me it seemed to be obvious trolling, an attempt to potentially harm users.

The flag was rejected so my question is:

Was that the proper flag to raise in this instance (likely not since it was rejected) or what the proper flag would be to raise instead (or that I shouldn't have raised a flag in the first place).

At the time that I flagged it I did not realize "F4" was in fact the key to open the window, so it is possible the asked made a mistake but I have my doubts.

Comment: That's mean-spirited, but not actually what "offensive" flags are for.  They are for posts that fail our [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.  Such as harassment, obscene language, and other rudeness.

Comment: IMHO *I have tried to customize the "Properties Window," which can be opened by "Alt+F4" hotkey.* is not rude

Comment: FFS. You cannot "force close" visual studio.  It still asks you if you want to save work before closing.  The only issue is people posting fake content, which is crap in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can edit something offensive/dangerous out of an otherwise OK post, edit it. Only flag if the OP keeps editing it back in or if they keep making those kinds of posts. Use a custom flag to explain the situation.

You really only want to use a rude/offensive flag if there's nothing salvageable in the post. This is because:

- You shouldn't flag a mod for something that the community can handle
- Those types of flags carry very heavy penalties and they don't want implement those if they aren't necessary

Comment: Oh okay, I instinctively thought the post was rude as it asks users to alt-f4 which is commonly used in a rude way but your points make a lot of sense. Thanks for the info, in the future I will raise a custom flag or try editing it first

Comment: @GordonAllocman I declined that flag. BSMP's answer here reflects my exact reasoning here - offensive flags should be used to indicate things that are *obviously offensive* - think antisemetic hate speech, "ima gonna come to your house" type stuff. If there's something wrong with a post that *isn't* obvious (and requires moderator attention), use a custom flag instead.